# Arborescent knots on Snappy

Tags: algorithms, knot-theory, python

Let $K\subset S^3$ be an arborescent knot represented by a plumbing graph $\Gamma$ (in the sense of "New Geometric Splitting of Classical Knots and Classification and Symmetries of Arborescent Knots" by F. Bonahon and L.C. Siebenmann). Is there a way to represent the knot K on Snappy using just $\Gamma$, avoiding drawing $K$ by hands?
I know that Snappy supports a short of tangle decomposition but it isn't clear to me how to use them.

For example how can I represent on Snappy the knot given by the following graph? (Please note that the integers are -from the left to the right, from top to bottom- -3,-2,0,-5,-7).

[image: Please note that the integers are (from the left to the right, from top to bottom) -3,-2,0,-5,-7)]

Comment: Is this a *math* problem, or a *coding* problem?

Comment: I guess it is a coding problem based on a mathematical one.

Comment: Then it really doesn't belong here but instead a programming site.  Is there a help site for *SnapPy*?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork No, SnapPy has a very small community, and I'm not sure there's any place except for here and MathOverflow where that community would even notice this question.

Comment: This week at the Sage Days Duluth workshop I extended the Tangle class to be more versatile, and it should be easier to enter links given graphs represented in this form. While I could pull up the paper, could you give a few more details about exactly how the graph corresponds to a link? Once the new Tangle class is merged into Spherogram I'll try to remember to get back to this and write an answer.

Comment: The graph corresponds to a link in the Gabai sense: see the paper "Genera of the arborescent links" by Gabai.  In a nutshell, every vertex of weight n corresponds to an n-twisted band (considering the sign of n), and every edge corresponds to a Murasugi's plumbing (square plumbing) between those bands.